# Subversion reintegrate mergeinfo Reverse-merged - how to undo?

Tags: svn, svn-reintegrate

> Hi
>   We use 1.6 SVN client.
>   We have 3 branches - trunk, branch A (created from trunk), branch B (created from A).
>   Revision r1 of trunk is blocked (using --record-only) in branch A with corresponding revision r2. 
>   Revision r2 of A is then merged to branch B with corresponding revision r3.

Branch B is to reintegrate with branch A.
After using svn merge --reintegrate, we notice the mergeinfo in branch A's working copy changed, displaying a list of revisions that we blocked many trunk revisions in branch A before.

Branch A mergeinfo below:

```
Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Modified: svn:mergeinfo
   Reverse-merged /proj/trunk:r181987,182079-182080,182143-182144,182192-182193,182228-182229,182278-182279,182322-182323,182353-182354,182386-182387,182420-182421,182469-182470,182513-182514,182552-182553,182622-182623,182673-182674,186045-186046,186049-186050,186058
   Merged /product/features/B:r184166-187801
```

How do we undo/recover (on command line) these "Reverse-merged" revisions in branch A's working copy before a svn commit such that mergeinfo would only show

```
Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Modified: svn:mergeinfo
   Merged /product/features/B:r184166-187801
```

Advance thanks for your help/answers

Answer (score 0):

> We use 1.6 SVN client.

You must not use SVN 1.6 client. You should use SVN 1.9.x or at least 1.8.x clients. There is no practical reason to use an outdated and unsupported SVN client or server version.

Update your client and server infrastructure and try [automatic reintegration merges](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.reintegrate) that were [introduced in SVN 1.8](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#auto-reintegrate). If you have any questions about merging in SVN, read the documentation:
[SVNBook | Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.html).